# Applescript works in Script Editor but not in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode5, applescript, applescript-objc

Good evening all,
I am trying to understand why I can run the below script in Applescript Editor but am unable to successfully run it in an Xcode Cocoa-Applescript application.

Can someone please explain why this function will not run in Xcode and what I need to do to have it run correctly?

```
set this_data to ((current date) as string) & space & "WHY DOESN'T THIS LOG!!!!" & return
set this_file to (((path to desktop folder) as string) & "MY LOG FILE")
my write_to_file(this_data, this_file, true)


on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data)
 try
    set the target_file to the target_file as string
    set the open_target_file to open for access file target_file with write permission
    if append_data is false then set eof of the open_target_file to 0
    write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof
    close access the open_target_file
    return true
 on error
    try
        close access file target_file
    end try
    return false
 end try
end write_to_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the Xcode behaviours I can't explain, but it works if you add `tell current application` like this:

```
tell current application to set the open_target_file to open for access file target_file with write permission
```

It might be better to put the whole function in a `tell current application` block.